# How can i know the cost for two functions?

Tags: c++

How can I calculate the cost for 2 function: Such as time to execute the function and memory size, reserved and availability for function 1 and the same for function 2

suppose i used this code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
    int factorial(int n);
    int factorial2(int n);

    int main ()
    {
                int n1,fact,fact2;
                cout <<"Enter the number whose factorial has to be calculated" <<  endl;
                cin >> n1;
                fact=factorial(n1);
                fact2=factorial2(n2);
                cout << "The factorial of " << n1 << "  is : " << fact << endl;
                return(0);      

    }

    int factorial(int n){
                int i=0,fact=1;
                if(n<=1)
                {
                            return(1);
                }
                else
                {
                            for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
                            {
                                        fact=fact*i;
                            }
                            return(fact);
                }
    }
    int factorial2(int n){
                int i=0,fact=1;
                if(n<=1)
                {
                            return(1);
                }
                else
                {
                            for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
                            {
                                        fact=fact*i;
                            }
                            return(fact);
                }
    }
```

Comment: Well, cost depends on how much a client will pay for your software. If the whole software is worth $100 and there are 200 functions inside, then each function costs 50 cents.

Comment: factorial and factorial2 are the same?

Comment: Perhaps he meant to write one of them with a recursive implementation.

Comment: i mean by the cost : time that the function 1 take it to execute.. memory size, memory reserved  and availability

Comment: this is example .. just i want to know how can i calculate the time that the function 1 take it to execute,,memory size, memory reserved and memory availability

Comment: @user1632359 Of course, I'm not an idiot :D It was just hilarious. See my answer and next time please `man 3 clock_gettime`.

Comment: @user1632359: How do you make function not available?

Comment: what do you mean, not available ?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews make it static inline and never use it - compiler will optimize out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `clock_gettime()` function to measure execution time, as per [this paper desribes.](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Time_a_function#C)